# Replace string by regex with specific value

Tags: php, regex

I have a substring like {[variable_name]} and want to replace it with the value of the variable specified in brackets.

```
/\{\[\s*[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\s*]}/
```

This is my regular expression, but I have no idea, what i should do next.
How do I?

Comment: Take a look at `preg_replace_callback()`. Also since you then need access to dynamic variable names in the callback you will need to use `global` with variable variables.

Comment: Or, in addition to @Rizier123, the `use` command.

Comment: @Jan OP won't be able to use `use()`. Think about it: OP will get the value of the variable name in the matches array, which gets passed to the callback. So he can't use it in `use()`.

Comment: @Rizier123: See my answer with using `use` in the callback function.

Comment: What are the requirements  for "variable_name"?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment, this would work:

```
<?php
$replacements = array();
$replacements["var1"] = "New variable here";
$regex = '~\{\[([^]]+)\]}~';

$string = "This is some string with {[var1]} in it";
$string = preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    function ($match) use ($replacements) {
        return $replacements[$match[1]];
    },
    $string);
echo $string;
# This is some string with New variable here in it
?>
```

See a demo <kbd>[on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/aAClj5)</kbd>.